# React: React-Palette "Element type is invalid: expected a string but got: object."

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use [react-palette](https://github.com/leonardokl/react-palette) to get the dominant color from an image. However I just can't seem to get it to work as I either get errors preventing my page from loading correctly, or it simply doesn't work.

Initially I thought the problem was with a conflict, so I tried using it in a separate clean install of react, but the problem still persists. I have tried using both examples suggested on the Github page, but neither works.

Using this example:

```
import Palette from 'react-palette';
// In your render...
<Palette src={"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Paracas_National_Reserve%2C_Ica%2C_Peru-3April2011.jpg"}>
  {({ data, loading, error }) => (
    <div style={{ color: data.vibrant }}>
      Text with the vibrant color
    </div>
  )}
</Palette>
```

I get:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

With this example:

```
import { usePalette } from 'react-palette'

const { data, loading, error } = usePalette("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Paracas_National_Reserve%2C_Ica%2C_Peru-3April2011.jpg")

<div style={{ color: data.vibrant }}>
  Text with the vibrant color
</div>
```

I simply get a normal  with text the same color as the body.

Am I doing something wrong? As far as I understand it the `color` of the text should change, but if I inspect my element the `color` isn't even assigned, most likely because the code isn't working.

EDIT: My full App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Palette from 'react-palette';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Palette src={'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Paracas_National_Reserve%2C_Ica%2C_Peru-3April2011.jpg'}>
        {({ data, loading, error }) => (
          <div style={{ color: data.vibrant }}>
            Text with the vibrant color
          </div>
        )}
      </Palette>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: did you place your Palette component and div in the render function?

Comment: Have you tried to log data, loading and error on your second example ?

Comment: Palette component is inside Render, yes. Second method actually seems to be working after logging it, so not sure what that's about. Any idea why the first one doesn't work though?

Comment: would you mind sharing the code you wrote based off each example?

Comment: My code is literally just the example. But sure, I edited the OP.

Comment: what react version are you on? I think I know what the problem is... or at least I have a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Palette component in `react-palette` is exported like this

```
export { Palette as default } from "./Palette";
```

Try changing the import to this

```
import { Palette } from 'react-palette';
```

Comment: That actually worked... Thank you, would've never thought of changing that.